# alert for confirm delete

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**Client Side Conformation**

```
var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete!");
if (answer)
 {
   alert ("Deleted.");  
 }
```

Here I want when it ask for confirmation in place of OK and Cancel I need Yes and No. How I can provide this?

Comment: You will have to create your own using div's and CSS or similar, the confirm dialog only has support for OK/Cancel. Also, if you're asking the user a question, make sure you use a question mark and not an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Those buttons you see are standard ones provided by the browser.

You would have to use an alternative JavaScript-based library like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to do this.

However note that those libraries require you to change your program flow, because they work in a different way than `confirm()` (You can't have the dialog function return the answer. See the demo code on the jQuery UI site to see what I mean.)

Comment: Since jQuery provides a promise-maker in the form of `Deferred` objects, you can get actually pretty close to the behavior. Like `$.when( MyDialog() ) { }`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to the below code to simulate a modal pop up.

JS:

```
window . open ('welcome.html', '', 'width=400,height=200');
```

Welcome.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   Thanks for visiting our web site.
   <p>
   <input
    type=button
    value="OK"
    onClick="window . close ();">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Source: http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/008.html